# Mailcore2 "ld: library not found for -licudata" when building

Tags: ios, mailcore, mailcore2

I've got a project which has been building fine using Mailcore2. I opened the project today and received errors along the lines of "SDK not found" during the Mailcore2 shell script. I discovered that I needed to rename .m files which import MailCore.h to .mm. I am now receiving the error "ld: library not found for -licudata" when building. This error is displayed within my target. My target's linker flags are as follows:

//:configuration = Debug
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -licudata -licui18n -licuuc -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -licucore -lc++ -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC

//:configuration = Release
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -licudata -licui18n -licuuc -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -licucore -lc++ -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC

In addition, I received "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'unordered_map' file not found" within the static mailcore2 ios target.

Nothing has changed within my build settings or configuration, and I haven't edited anything in the project. I literally just opened it and tried to build.

Comment: If you're using Cocoapods, you don't need to link with tidy, sasl2 and icucore.

Comment: I'm not using cocoa pods, I followed the instructions on adding the Mailcore2 Xcode project to my app project and linking manually. Is this no longer supported? Should I switch to cocoa pods?

Comment: Oh ok. The instructions have been updated since. https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md . Use `-luchardet-ios -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -lc++ -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC`

Comment: Thank you. I switched to using the Cocoapods build and it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the cocoa pods version solved the problem and was much easier to install and use than the older xcodeproj version.